# NTFS permissions: Allow creation / modification / deletion of folders and subfolders and files only with a UAC prompt

Tags: windows, permissions, uac, ntfs

I have a folder without any inherited permissions. I want to configure it in a way that allows reading all subfolders and files like usual but shows a UAC prompt if I try to create/modify/delete files or folders (just like C:\Program Files). I am logged in as an administrator. Can you tell me how I need to configure the NTFS permissions? Thanks, English is not my native language so I hope you understood me :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I have figured it out :) For anyone who is interested in how to do it:

- Allow full control for the group "Administrators"
- Allow only read control for your administrator account.
  Now i get a UAC prompt everytime i try to modify something.